# need to replace some underscores with hypens

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column with value

`AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg`

I need to replace the middle underscores so that it displays it as date i.e.

`AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10-28-2014_123456.jpg`

Can some one please suggest a simple update query for this.

The Number of Underscores would be same for all the values in the column but the length will vary for example some can have

`AAA_q10WRQ_001_10_28_2014_12.jpg`

Comment: All of the values in the column have the same format 3 letters, underscore, 4 letters, underscore, etc...? If so, you should look http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/874555-replacing-8th-character-varchar-string

Comment: I was trying CHARINDEX() and Substring(), but unable to get the required result

Comment: I would do this with regex and .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30384/0

```
declare @filename varchar(64) = 'AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg'
declare @datepattern varchar(64) = '%[_][0-1][0-9][_][0-3][0-9][_][1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%'

select
  filename,
  substring(filename,1,datepos+2)+'-'+
  substring(filename,datepos+4,2)+'-'+
  substring(filename,datepos+7,1000)
from
(
  select
    @filename filename,
    patindex(@datepattern,@filename)
      as datepos
) t
;
```

Resulting in

```
AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10-28-2014_123456.jpg
```

Caveats to watch out for:

- It is important to *exactly* define how you find the date. In my definition it is MM_DD_YYYY surrounded by further two underscores, and I check that the first digits of M,D,Y are 0-1,0-3,1-2 respectively (i.e. I do NOT check if month is e.g. 13.) -- of course we assume that there is only one such string in any file name.
- `datepos` actually finds the position of the underscore before the date -- this is not an issue if taken into account in the indexing of `substring`.
- in the 3rd substring the length cannot be `NULL` or infinity and I couldn't get `LEN()` to work in SQL Fiddle so I dirty hardcoded a large enough number (1000). Corrections to this are welcome.

Comment: @user2262518 you are welcome! If you believe that I answered your question, best is to 'accept' it by clicking on the tick mark top right of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that the DATE portion always starts at the same character index)

```
declare @string varchar(64) = 'AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg'
select replace(@string, reverse(substring(reverse(@string), charindex('_', reverse(@string), 0) + 1, 10)), replace(reverse(substring(reverse(@string), charindex('_', reverse(@string), 0) + 1, 10)), '_', '-'))
```

Comment: In my case the date portion varies, So i was trying substring() and replace() functions to see if it can be done

Comment: Is there anything constant (start position of date, distance of date from the end, etc.)?

Comment: the only constant is number of underscores and they are 6.

Comment: I edited my answer.  This should work for your case assuming 1) There is only one "_" after the date portion and 2) the date portion is always 10 characters long

Answer (score 0):

If there are exactly 6 _ then for the first

select STUFF ( 'AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg' , CHARINDEX ( '_' ,'AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg', CHARINDEX ( '_' ,'AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg', CHARINDEX ( '_' ,'AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg', CHARINDEX ( '_' ,'AAA_ZZZZ_7890_10_28_2014_123456.jpg', 0 ) + 1 ) + 1 ) + 1 ) , 1 , '-' )